# How can i convert mnist data to RGB format?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to convert MNIST dataset to RGB format, the actual shape of each image is (28, 28), but i need (28, 28, 3).

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()

X = np.concatenate([x_train, x_test])
X = X / 127.5 - 1

X.reshape((70000, 28, 28, 1))

tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(
    X,
    name=None
)
```

But i get the following error:

```
ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 84 and 3. Shapes are [28,84] and [28,3].
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store the reshaped 3D [28x28x1] images in an array:

```
X = X.reshape((70000, 28, 28, 1))
```

When converting, set an other array to the return value of the `tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb()` function  :

```
X3 = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(
X,
name=None
)
```

Finally, to plot out one example from the resulting tensor images with `matplotlib` and `tf.session()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    image_to_plot = sess.run(image)
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image_to_plot)
    plt.grid(False)
```

The complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()

X = np.concatenate([x_train, x_test])
X = X / 127.5 - 1

# Set reshaped array to X 
X = X.reshape((70000, 28, 28, 1))

# Convert images and store them in X3
X3 = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(
    X,
    name=None
)

# Get one image from the 3D image array to var. image
image = X3[0,:,:,:]

# Plot it out with matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    image_to_plot = sess.run(image)
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image_to_plot)
    plt.grid(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print the shape of X before tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb you will see the output dimension is (70000, 28, 28). Inputs to tf.image.grayscale must have size 1 as it's final dimension.

Expand the final dimension of X to make it compatible with the function

```
tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(tf.expand_dims(X, axis=3))
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem since you are still not returning the output of the conversion function.

Comment: Sure, I should have returned the function output, however it's incorrect to say it does not fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @DMolony and @Aqwis01 answers, another simple solution could be using `numpy.repeat` method to duplicate the last dimension of your tensor several times:

```py
X = X.reshape((70000, 28, 28, 1))
X = X.repeat(3, -1)  # repeat the last (-1) dimension three times
X_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(X)
assert X_t.shape == (70000, 28, 28, 3)
```